# node-gyp configure build errors on WIndows 10

Tags: visual-studio, npm, node-gyp

link to the log: [Here](https://hastebin.com/raw/wimenaduxa)

I Currently have Visual Studio 2017 installed. Thought that may be relevant. Also have python 2.7.3. Any help would be amazing!

Edit: Turns out I also have VS2010 Express installed.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your VS2010 and VS2017

Install all the required tools and configurations using Microsoft's windows-build-tools using npm install --global --production windows-build-tools from an elevated PowerShell or CMD.exe (run as Administrator).

Comment: Do you mean to say you can't use/install the windows-build-tools npm without uninstalling existing VS installations first???